# WebSocket connection to 'ws://chattestarpit.herokuapp.com/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 503

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket

I am new to WebSocket (webRTC).I created a video chat app.  it's working on localhost.

**Server**

```
    app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8081, function () {  
   console.log("Example app listening at 8081" )
});
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendfile('index.html');
});
//require our websocket library 
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server; 

//creating a websocket server at port 9090 
var wss = new WebSocketServer({server: app}); 

//all connected to the server users 
var users = {};
```

**Client**

```
//connecting to our signaling server
var HOST = location.origin.replace(/^http/, 'ws');
var conn = new WebSocket(HOST);

conn.onopen = function () { 
   console.log("Connected to the signaling server"); 
};
```

Heroku showing some problem with WebSocket. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are running your server on port 8081, while on the client you are trying to connect to the default port for web socket i.e. 80. try including the 8081 port number from the client request.

Comment: If i use same port both side,  it works on localhost but it has some problem with heroku..  
Chattestarpit.herokuapp.com.
Please check console.  
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you see "heroku logs", then you can find that the port on which app is running is a random 5 digit number. ( like 28896, 53365, etc.) It never actually runs on the second half || 8081.

You need to debug the actual root cause, what you can do is

- Open terminal at your app folder
- Type command `heroku logs -t --app <your-app-name>`
- It will give all logs, including your nodejs based consoles
- Based on that apply fixes accordingly

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

For me is was got the port from `process.env.PORT` and then it starts to work.

Heroku ignore completely my '.dev`s file